# Struts2 - How to repopulate form having dynamically generated fieldnames (via expression) with submitted values after validation error

Tags: java, struts2

We have a Struts2 application where we are building survey feature using which application users will be able to create surveys by adding different questions.

These questions are comprised of question text and an html control for getting response.

The html controls so far supported are *single* and *multi-select list*, *text field*, *textarea*, *checkbox* and *radiobox*.

So the survey form renders displaying all questions added by the user where each question has its question text displayed followed by the html field control selected for that question.

Basically, it is a dynamic form where form field names are being dynamically generated as all surveys will be different and therefore there are no properties in the Action class backing survey form fields.

We are generating form field name using prefix `question_` appended with database id of the question to represent each question response input field uniquely. Here is a snippet from our JSP page to make things clear.

```html
    <s:form id="surveyForm" action="survey/submitFeedback">

      <s:iterator value="surveyQuestions">
        <p class="form-group <s:if test="%{fieldErrors.get('question_' + surveyQuestionId).size() > 0}">has-error</s:if>" >
          <label class="control-label" >
            <s:property value="questionText"/>
          </label>
          <s:if test="required" ><span style='color:red'>*</span></s:if>
          <br>
          <s:if test="surveyQuestionType.type == @com.reach150.enumeration.SurveyQuestionTypeEnum@OPENENDED_TEXTFIELD" >
            <s:textfield name="question_%{surveyQuestionId}" cssClass="form-control" maxlength="charactersLimit" />
          </s:if>
          <s:elseif test="surveyQuestionType.type == @com.reach150.enumeration.SurveyQuestionTypeEnum@OPENENDED_TEXTAREA" >
            <s:textarea name="question_%{surveyQuestionId}" style="height: 150px; width: 400px;" cssClass="form-control" maxlength="charactersLimit" />
          </s:elseif>
          <s:elseif test="surveyQuestionType.type == @com.reach150.enumeration.SurveyQuestionTypeEnum@SINGLESELECTDROPDOWN || surveyQuestionType.type == @com.reach150.enumeration.SurveyQuestionTypeEnum@MULTISELECTDROPDOWN" >
            <s:select name="question_%{surveyQuestionId}" list="orderedSelectOptions" listKey="optionValue" listValue="optionLabel" emptyOption="true" multiple="true" cssClass="form-control" />
          </s:elseif>
          <s:else>
            <s:radio name="question_%{surveyQuestionId}" list="#{'true':'Yes','false':'No'}" cssClass="radioMarginRight" />
          </s:else>
          <span class="help-block" for="question_${surveyQuestionId}">
            <s:fielderror cssClass="font-bold text-danger">
              <s:param>question_<s:property value="surveyQuestionId" /></s:param>
            </s:fielderror>
          </span>
          <br/>
        </p>      
      </s:iterator>      
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right "><s:if test="survey.requestReferral == true">Next</s:if><s:else>Done</s:else></button>
      
    </s:form>
```

On form submit, in the action class we are using `HttpServletRequest` to get submitted form field values. The way we identify which question the answer belongs to is through the request parameter name which as can be seen in the above JSP snippet starts with prefix 'question_' followed by question Id. So we split the parameter name to get the question id and associate value against that question.

The problem we are facing is with repopulating survey form with submitted values when the page is presented back to the user in case of validation error as the parameter names are dynamic and cannot be backed by properties defined in Action class.

I have tried to populate *radio button* and *textarea* fields using the below code and several other ways but to no avail

```html
    <s:textarea name="question_%{surveyQuestionId}" style="height: 150px; width: 400px;" cssClass="form-control" maxlength="charactersLimit" value="#parameters.%{'question_' + surveyQuestionId}" />

    <s:radio name="question_%{surveyQuestionId}" value="#parameters.%{'question_' + surveyQuestionId}" list="#{'true':'Yes','false':'No'}" cssClass="radioMarginRight" />
```

Below is the action mapping for survey submit action

```html
<action name="survey/submitFeedback" class="surveyAction" method="submitFeedback">
    <result name="success" type="tiles">survey.submit</result>
    <result name="error" type="tiles">survey.view</result>
    <param name="public">true</param>
</action>
```

Here is the code in Action class handling the submit logic:

```
private Integer npsScore = 0;
private Map<String, String[]> surveyResponseQuestionAnswerMap = new HashMap<>();

    public String submitFeedback() {

    try {
        if (requestId == null) {
            addActionError("Request Id missing! Invalid Request!");
            throw new Exception("Invalid Request!");
        }
        
        surveyRequest = surveyService.getSurveyRequestByUUID(requestId);
        if (surveyRequest == null) {
            addActionError("Request Id Invalid! Invalid Request!");
            throw new Exception("Request Id Invalid! Invalid Request!");
        }
        loadQuestionAnswersMap();
        validateSurveyFeedback();
        
        if (hasErrors()) {
            throw new Exception("Error submitting response!");
        } else {
            surveyService.parseAndSaveSurveyResponse(surveyRequest, surveyResponseQuestionAnswerMap);
            setSurveyCustomMessages(surveyService.getSurveyCustomMessagesSettingBySurveyId(survey.getSurveyId()));
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        addActionError("Error submitting response!");
        logger.error(e);
        loadSurvey();
        return ERROR;
    }
}

private void loadQuestionAnswersMap() {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = ActionUtil.getRequest();
    Enumeration<String> parameterNames = httpRequest.getParameterNames();
    while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String parameterName = parameterNames.nextElement();
        if (parameterName.startsWith("question_")) {
            String[] values = httpRequest.getParameterValues(parameterName);
            if (values != null) {
                surveyResponseQuestionAnswerMap.put(parameterName, values);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void validateSurveyFeedback() throws Exception {
    
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = ActionUtil.getRequest();
    Survey survey = surveyRequest.getSurvey();
    if (survey.isUseNetPromotorScore()) {
        String npsScoreStr = httpRequest.getParameter("npsScore");
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(npsScoreStr)) {
            this.addFieldError("npsScore", "Answer is required");
        } else {
            setNpsScore(Integer.valueOf(npsScoreStr));
        }
    }
    List<SurveyQuestion> requiredQuestions = surveyQuestionService.getRequiredSurveyQuestionsForSurvey(surveyRequest.getSurvey());
    for (SurveyQuestion requiredQuestion : requiredQuestions) {
        Integer requiredQuestionId = requiredQuestion.getSurveyQuestionId();
        String requiredQuestionFieldParameterName = "question_" + requiredQuestionId;
        logger.info("Required Question Field Parameter Name: " + requiredQuestionFieldParameterName);
        String[] answers = httpRequest.getParameterValues(requiredQuestionFieldParameterName);
        if (answers == null) {
            this.addFieldError(requiredQuestionFieldParameterName, "Answer is required");
        } else {
            boolean noValue = true;
            for (String answer : answers) {
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(answer)) {
                    noValue = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (noValue) {
                this.addFieldError(requiredQuestionFieldParameterName, "Answer is required");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible without code. If you have a specific problem or error then you should write it to the question. If you don't know how to write a codе then the basics are in the [documentation](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started).

Comment: Hi @RomanC, not sure I understood correctly what you mean by _It's not possible without code_. We have a Struts2 application where it is the first time we are required to have dynamic forms where form field names are not known before hand. As you can see in the second code-snippet above, when I try to set the value of text area to the value of request parameter name resolved by `#parameters.%{'question_' + surveyQuestionId}`, instead of getting the parameter value it resolves to the text 'question_2' getting displayed in the text area, where 2 is value of property `surveyQuestionId`.

Comment: Similarly, the radio box does get pre-selected if I hard-code the value in `s:radio` tag value attribute to `#parameters.question_4` instead of `#parameters.%{'question_' + surveyQuestionId}`. However, as the question id depends on the current question object in iteration, it is not possible to hard-code the question id value. I hope I have  explained better here.

Comment: The code, I mean the relevant code should be posted. We need to see how parameters are handled by the action class. We also need to see the `struts.xml` for better understanding the action flow. We don't use low level objects like `HttpServletRequest` to retrieve parameters. Event if you know how to get parameters from the action context using OGNL, you should also know how to use `params` interceptor to populate them to the action. Although there's better way to handle multiple parameters using indexes...

Comment: ...IMHO if you use dynamic variables then they should be created on the server before the view result is returned, so the variables could be preselected from the value stack by the `prepare` interceptor. It would be better if you use the validation on the action flow. And why you should do this all. Because what are you trying to achieve is a double evaluation of the OGNL expression which I think is discoveraged in S2.

Comment: Hi @RomanC, I have edited the post and added action mapping as well as Action class code to the post. Can you suggest a any example or tutorial link that may help me in achieving it the way you are recommending. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have finally solved the problem. The initial implementation was heading in a completely wrong direction but thanks to the clue from @RomanC, we re-factored the code and removed the direct use of `HttpServletRequest` to finally have a working solution. Core idea was to use a Bean for capturing response and have a `List` of those beans in the Action class corresponding to each survey question. On form submit, response is captured into the bean objects behind the scene by framework itself and thus available for further logic processing in submit handler action method.